# Rails i18n - How to translate model in fields_for that has_one inherited model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-i18n

I have the following models:

```
class AccountMovement < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :accounting_document
  ..
end

class AccountingDocument < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account_movement
  ..
end

class CreditNote < AccountingDocument
  ..
end

class Invoice < AccountingDocument
  ..
end
```

Users can add credit notes

```
<%= form_with model: @credit |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :account_movement do |ff| %>
    <div>
      <%= ff.label :amount %>
      <%= ff.number_field(:amount, step: 0.01, autofocus: true) %>
    </div>
    ...
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

The website only supports Portuguese, thus I added the following translation

```
pt:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      account_movement:
        amount: 'Valor'
```

But it fails to automatically translate the amount attribute of account_movement. This works fine on a has_one relationship when the form looks like this

```
<%= form_with model: @account_movement |f| %>

  <div>
    <%= f.label :amount %>
    <%= f.number_field(:amount, step: 0.01, autofocus: true) %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :credit_note do |ff| %>
    ...
  <% end %>

  ...
<% end %>
```

I already tried many approaches without success

```
pt:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      account_movement:
        amount: 'Valor'
      credit_note/account_movement:
        amount: 'Valor'
      credit_note[account_movement]:
        amount: 'Valor'
      credit_note_account_movement:
        amount: 'Valor'
```

Am I missing something or automatically translation of inverse has_onde relationships in a fields_for isn't supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It was missing the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :account_movement` at `AccoutingDocument`

```
class AccountingDocument < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account_movement

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :account_movement
  ..
end
```

No need to add extra translation at locals

```
pt:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      account_movement:
        amount: 'Valor'
```